# Can't install gem mysql2

Tags: ruby-on-rails

There is a piece of code in Gemfile:

```
group :production do
  gem 'pg'
    gem 'mysql2'
end
```

I execute 'bundle install', all is good. But when I try to make 'RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake db:migrate' I get the message: `Specified 'mysql2' for database adapter, but the gem is not loaded. Add`gem 'mysql2'`to your Gemfile.` What's the trouble? How can I fix it? Thanks!

Comment: Why are you installing two DB adapters for `production`?

Comment: I thought to use PostgreSQL, but now I need to use MySQL

Comment: You should get rid of `gem pg` then - have you tried `bundle install` ?

Comment: Normally in ROR, we prefer `pg` for production mode, why are you using  `mysql2` on production mode?